# Can't boot any Linux except Ubuntu

Tags: boot

Hello I wanted to switch to Linux, but the only distro so far I could even boot from a live USB was Ubuntu. I've tried Xubuntu, Manjaro, Linux Mint, and Elementary OS and none could boot, thought when I tried booting them on my old laptop , everything went fine.

The laptop I'm using is a Lenovo Y500 and yeah I tried disabling secure boot but nothing worked. So is there a way to fix this or do I have to use Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there any error messages accompanying this when you attempt to boot these other distros?

Comment: Nope it's just a blank , almost black screen , I do get the options to try or install the distro but when I chose try it just goes blank like I said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this AU Q&A: [Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Y500](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272570/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-y500). There are some suggestions you could try from this thread.

I also found these things to try. I do not know how relevant they are, but might be worth trying: [linlap.com/lenovo_ideapad_y500](http://www.linlap.com/lenovo_ideapad_y500).

This AU Q&A also looks related: [Lenovo Y500 Dual Booting Ubuntu and Windows 8: Stuck on Purple Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290329/lenovo-y500-dual-booting-ubuntu-and-windows-8-stuck-on-purple-screen).